# returning a class from its member function

Tags: c#

Is it possible to define a  member function which have the return type same as the class where  it is a  member.

eg:

```
public class Cars
{
 int Model
 int Make

  Cars CreateDeepCopy()
   {
       using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
           var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
           formatter.Serialize(ms, this);
           ms.Position = 0;
           return (Cars)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
       }

    }


  }
```

Comment: Sure, why not? PS: it is easier to try rather than ask

Comment: @zerkms thanks. i was trying to get any negative sides of this implementation.

Comment: how is possibility related to "negative sides"?

Comment: @zerkms You won :) I expected people will point out if something is wrong in my code + possibility. My fault.

Comment: @logeeks: FYI this is often used to create a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), see the C# example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make sure you polish the syntax to make it valid C# in order to compile and that you decorate your class with the `[Serializable]` attribute or you won't be able to use a BinaryFormatter to serialize it:

```
[Serializable]
public class Cars
{
    public int Model;
    public int Make;

    public Cars CreateDeepCopy()
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, this);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (Cars)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using the exact syntax you are using in the example. Note however that this won't respect inheritance, so if you have a **subclass** of `Cars`, `CreateDeepCopy` would still be typed as `Cars` (although the returned object would be the sub-type, due to how `BinaryFormatter` works). This can be addressed via "method hiding" if required, i.e.

```
[Serializable] class SomeSpecialCar : Cars {
    new public SomeSpecialCar CreateDeepCopy() {
       return (SomeSpecialCar)base.CreateDeepCopy();
    }
}
```

note also that `Cars` seems to represent a single instance, so should probably be `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, whats wrong with your implementation? return null outside using block and it should be file. You can return same instance as well as new or default instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. To clone your class, you might implement [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) instead of your `CreateDeepCopy` method. It returns an object, however, which requires the caller to cast it back to `Cars`.

Comment: `ICloneable` is generally out-of-favor, since it is ambiguous whether it is a deep vs shallow clone. Arguably in this case it won't matter, but since the **caller** shouldn't know much about the implementation, the caller therefore probably can't trust `ICloneable`

Comment: OK, didn't know that. Is there a generally accepted practice like `CreateDeepCopy` or maybe copy-constructors?